# Jquery Mobile Maximum # of pages?

Tags: jquery, mobile

I couldn't seem to find this anywhere, but is there a maximum number of pages that can be created using the div tag:

```
<div data-role="page">
```

I have maybe 6 or so pages made, and the last one won't load. It just gives me a spinner. But if I was to remove a page that works, then the last one will render.

Thanks!

Comment: I had an issue like this, turned out to be a javascript conflict nothing to do with jqmobile. Worth mentioning.

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Just fyi, the loading icon spins continously

Comment: So I just removed my javascript all together, and it still has this problem.

Comment: hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Found what it was, my fault. I missing a closing div tag on one of my pages. Thanks!

Comment: awesome, glad you got it!